# selecting field text with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am using the below code to select a fields text with JavaScript but it doesn't quite work:

```
//auto select that fields text for easy COPY

var content = parent.document.getElementById('share_field_<?php echo $id; ?>');
content.focus();
content.select();
```

Field to select:

//share field

```
echo '<div class="name" style="display: none" id="share_field_'.$row['id'].'"><input name="share" type="text" value="http://www.site.com/play/'.$row['id'].'" size="53"></div>';
```

Comment: is that even javascript?

Comment: no of course not. i only use hypercard...

Comment: Aren't you selecting the div instead of the input field?

Comment: Jitter. Thanks. Write that up as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

```
var content = parent.document.getElementById('share_field_<?php echo $id; ?>');
content.firstChild.focus();
content.firstChild.select();
```